# HTML to Docx in angular

Tags: javascript, html, docx, doc

I have an HTML snippet that I want to save as a .docx file. Currently, I am getting a distorted result in which the content is not well-fetched and not positioned properly.

**Below is my codebase**

```
var html = document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML;

    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
      type: 'application/msword'
    });

    // Specify link url
    var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);

    // Specify file name
    // String filename = 'document.doc';

    // Create download link element
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'document.doc');
    }
    else {
      // Create a link to the file
      downloadLink.href = url;

      // Setting the file name
      downloadLink.download = 'document.doc';

      //triggering the function
      downloadLink.click();
    }

    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  }


  changePerPageItems(e) {
    this.perPageItems = e.target.value;
  }
```

Is there anything that is needed to be changed. Or any new method is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to implement this (according to me) is using the docx.js

I have added simple example and link to example and documentation

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-afvxtz

https://docx.js.org/#/

TS file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Packer } from 'docx';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver/FileSaver';

import { DocumentCreator } from './cv-generator';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  public download(): void {
    const documentCreator = new DocumentCreator();
    const doc = documentCreator.create();
    doc.createParagraph("Test heading1, bold and italicized").heading1();
    doc.createParagraph("Some simple content");
    const packer = new Packer();

    packer.toBlob(doc).then(blob => {
      console.log(blob);
      saveAs(blob, "example.docx");
      console.log("Document created successfully");
    });
  }
}
```

cv-generator.ts file:

```
import { Document, Paragraph, Packer, TextRun } from 'docx';


export class DocumentCreator {
  create() {
    const title = 'EXECUTIVE SUMMARY';
    const document = new Document();
    document.addParagraph(new Paragraph(title).title());
    document.addParagraph(this.createHeading('Exception Overview'));
    return document;
  }
  createHeading(text) {
    return new Paragraph(text).heading1().thematicBreak();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="em-primary-button" (click)="download()">Download file</button>
```

Credit: Asif Karim Bherani

Answer (score 0):

### A simple parser implementation

I wrote this for running it on client side of Typescript NextJS application because most online available libraries (as of Apr 21, 2023) like `html-to-docx`, `html-docx`, `html-docx-js` on npm are either `missing type definitions` or `import fs` on client side which lead to errors.

It can handle following elements:

- <br>
- <h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5>, <h6>
- <p>
- <li>

Feel free to extend it for your use-case.

### Parser Code:

```js
import { Document, Paragraph, Packer, TextRun, HeadingLevel, LevelFormat, AlignmentType, convertInchesToTwip } from 'docx';

const bullet_points_config = {
    reference: "my-bullet-points",
    levels: [
        {
            level: 0,
            format: LevelFormat.BULLET,
            text: "\u2022",
            alignment: AlignmentType.LEFT,
            style: {
                paragraph: {
                    indent: { left: convertInchesToTwip(0.5), hanging: convertInchesToTwip(0.25) },
                },
            },
        },
    ],
}


export const parseNode = (root: Element, parents_array: any[], children_paras: Paragraph[]): void => {
    // console.log(root, root.childNodes.length);
    if (root.childNodes.length === 0) {
        if (root.tagName == "BR") {
            children_paras.push(new Paragraph({
                children: [
                    new TextRun({
                        text: "",
                        break: 1,
                    })
                ]
            }))
        }
        else {
            children_paras.push(new Paragraph({
                text: root.textContent?.trim() || "",
                heading: parents_array.at(-1)?.tagName == "H1" ?
                    HeadingLevel.HEADING_1 :
                    parents_array.at(-1)?.tagName == "H2" ?
                        HeadingLevel.HEADING_2 :
                        parents_array.at(-1)?.tagName == "H3" ?
                            HeadingLevel.HEADING_3 :
                            parents_array.at(-1)?.tagName == "H4" ?
                                HeadingLevel.HEADING_4 :
                                parents_array.at(-1)?.tagName == "H5" ?
                                    HeadingLevel.HEADING_5 :
                                    parents_array.at(-1)?.tagName == "H6" ?
                                        HeadingLevel.HEADING_6 :
                                        undefined,
                numbering: parents_array.at(-1)?.tagName == "LI" ? {
                    reference: "my-bullet-points",
                    level: 0,
                } : undefined,
            }))
        }
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < root.childNodes.length; i++) {
            const element = root.childNodes[i];
            parseNode(element as Element, [...parents_array, root], children_paras)
        }
    }


}

export const htmlToDocsParser = (html: string): Document => {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    let parents_array: any[] = [];
    let child_array: Paragraph[] = [];
    parseNode(doc.body, parents_array, child_array)
    const out = new Document({
        numbering: {
            config: [bullet_points_config]
        },
        sections: [
            {
                children: child_array
            }
        ]
    })
    return out;
}
```

### Usage:

```js
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";
import { Document, Paragraph, Packer, TextRun } from "docx";

htmlstring=`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- ADD YOUR HTML HERE -->
        </body>
    </html>

`
const final_doc = htmlToDocsParser(htmlString)
await Packer.toBlob(final_doc).then((blob) => {
                // save file to disk
                saveAs(
                  blob,
                  `filename.docx`
                );
                console.log("Document created successfully");
              });
```